# How to read data from SQL server and update SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Is there any code sample to read the external SQL table data and create a list in SharePoint 2013, thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple example via c# SSOM to retrieve Records from SQLdatabase table to existing SharePoint list

**1. Create a function to get your data from SQL server and return it to a data table.**

```
    // your method to pull data from database to datatable   
    public DataTable GetDatafromSQL()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();            
        string connString = @"your connection string here";
        string query = "select * from table";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        // create data adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();
        da.Dispose();
        return dataTable;
    }
```

**2. Create a function that loop for every item at the retrieved SQL data table and adds it to list.**

```
     void binditems()
     {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt= GetDatafromSQL();

     using (SPSite oSite=new SPSite("http://mysharepoint"))
      {

       using (SPWeb oWeb=oSite.RootWeb)
        {
            SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Test"];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
            {
            SPListItem oSPListItem = oList.Items.Add();
            oSPListItem["Title"] = row["Title"].ToString();
            oSPListItem.Update();
            }
        }
     }
     }
```

Read the Function `binditems()`, to can bind the data from SQL to List

**Note** : don't forget to include this namespaces `using System.Data.SqlClient;`    `using Microsoft.SharePoint;`

Comment: Hi Qassas, Connection string throws null reference. How to add sql connection string to SharePoint webconfig file

Comment: Hi @samdaniel should you share wha't is your provided connection string line ? for add sql connection string to SP web.config check this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msjimblog/2012/07/31/where-to-store-your-custom-sql-connection-strings-in-sharepoint/

Comment: @Qassas The name 'dr["Title"]' does not exit in current context. How to fix this? thanks in advance

Comment: @samdaniel replace it with row to be row["Title"].ToString(); please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification or face another issue